# How check status of Web Camera using Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera, video-streaming

I have a setup of web application and Hardware(which has camera integrated), My job is to

1.Check cam in hardware is capturing video(when a video call is initiated from the web application to Hardware).
2.Check cam in my laptop is capturing video(when a video call is initiated from hardware to web application).

I don't want to capture video from Cam, All I need to check the status of Camera(whether it is capturing video or not).Is there any way to check this scenario using python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly check if a camera is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049886/how-to-correctly-check-if-a-camera-is-available)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you're looking for:`yourCamVar.isOpened()`. This checks if it's capturing video.

Lots of information on that [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if cap.isOpened():
        print("Webcam online.")

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```