# How to correctly check if a camera is available?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV to open and read from several webcams. It all works fine, but I cannot seem to find a way to know if a camera is available.

I tried this code (cam 2 does not exist):

```
import cv2
try:
    c = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
except:
    print "Cam 2 is invalid."
```

But this just prints a lot of errors:

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: index 2 is not correct!
failed to open /usr/lib64/dri/hybrid_drv_video.so
Failed to wrapper hybrid_drv_video.so
failed to open /usr/lib64/dri/hybrid_drv_video.so
Failed to wrapper hybrid_drv_video.so
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Internal data stream error.
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-3.2.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 832
VIDEOIO(cvCreateCapture_GStreamer(CV_CAP_GSTREAMER_V4L2, reinterpret_cast<char *>(index))): raised OpenCV exception:

/builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-3.2.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:832: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
 in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (unicap: failed to get info for device
) in CvCapture_Unicap::initDevice, file /builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-3.2.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_unicap.cpp, line 139
VIDEOIO(cvCreateCameraCapture_Unicap(index)): raised OpenCV exception:

/builddir/build/BUILD/opencv-3.2.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_unicap.cpp:139: error: (-2) unicap: failed to get info for device
 in function CvCapture_Unicap::initDevice

CvCapture_OpenNI::CvCapture_OpenNI : Failed to enumerate production trees: Can't create any node of the requested type!
<VideoCapture 0x7fa5b5de0450>
```

No exception is thrown. When using `c.read()` later, I do get `False`, but I would like to do this in the initialisation phase of my program.

So, how do I find out how many valid cameras I have or check if a certain number 'maps' to a valid one?

Comment: "*no exception is thrown*": yes, because you caught them all unhandled. Always only catch the exceptions you're willing to handle.

Comment: @AndrasDeak the `print "Cam 2 is invalid"` is never shown.

Comment: Ah, that makes it a bit more interesting (but I stand by my earlier statement). So...what kind of errors does it print? Please read [mcve] and [ask] :P

Comment: @AndrasDeak adding `import cv2` was all that was needed to make this MCV. I added the errors as well.

Comment: Úsing `cv2.VideoCapture( invalid device number )` does not throw exceptions. It constructs a  `<VideoCapture object>` containing an invalid device - if you use it you get exceptions. Test the constructed object for `None` and `not IsOpen()` to weed out invalid ones. See answer for code example.

Comment: @PatrickArtner that works, but it outputs an awful lot of errors in my console.

Comment: Using Win8.1, VS2017 with 3.6.2 and opencv-python 3.4.0.12 - no warnings in console.  Does the code *not work* or *work* and pollute your console? If latter, they might be warnings from cv2

Comment: Fedora 27, OpenCV 3.2.0, Python 2.7.14, many errors. But they look like they come from V4L, so there is not much I can do I am afraid.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `cv2.VideoCapture( invalid device number )` does not throw exceptions. It constructs a `<VideoCapture object>` containing an invalid device - if you *use* it you get exceptions.

Test the constructed object for `None` and `not isOpened()` to weed out invalid ones.

---

For me this works (1 laptop camera device):

```
import cv2 as cv 

def testDevice(source):
   cap = cv.VideoCapture(source) 
   if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
       print('Warning: unable to open video source: ', source)

testDevice(0) # no printout
testDevice(1) # prints message
```

Output with 1:

```
Warning: unable to open video source:  1
```

Example from: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/samples/python2/video.py
lines 159ff

> ```
> cap = cv.VideoCapture(source)
>     if 'size' in params:
>         w, h = map(int, params['size'].split('x'))
>         cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w)
>         cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, h)
> if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
>     print 'Warning: unable to open video source: ', source
> ```

Comment: "Non-existent device" is at the core of this question: how to tell if a device at a given source ID is not available.

Comment: @AndrasDeak had to install opencv first to test it - for me it works - no crash

Comment: The example from opencv_contrib does not check if `cv2.VideoCapture()` returns `None`—it checks whether `classes.get(params.get('class', None), VideoSynthBase) is None`. See the whole thing: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/57ff3633893945876726cb98e6c2c982b911b733/samples/python2/video.py#L153-L164

Comment: The proposed solution does not work for Point Grey (FLIR) cameras. Neither does my `cam.Init()` idea posted here.

Comment: I have found in practice that `cv::VideoCapture()` _does_ throw exceptions under some circumstances (OpenCV 3.1.0 because upgrading is hard). Beware.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution, which is available in Linux is to use the `/dev/videoX` device in the `VideoCapture()` call. The devices are there when the cam is plugged in. Together with `glob()`, it is trivial to get all the cameras:

```
import cv2, glob

for camera in glob.glob("/dev/video?"):
    c = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)
```

Of course a check is needed on `c` using `isOpened()`, but you are sure you only scan the available cameras.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **"NOT working"** solution to help you prevent tumbling over in this pitfall:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import PySpin

print (cv.__version__)

# provided by Patrick Artner as solution to be working for other cameras than
#                                                  those of Point Grey (FLIR).

def testDevice(source):
   cap = cv.VideoCapture(source) 
   if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
       print('Warning: unable to open video source: ', source)

# ... PySpin / Spinnaker (wrapper/SDK libary) ...

system   = PySpin.System.GetInstance()
cam_list = system.GetCameras()

cam = ''
cam_num = 0

for ID, cam in enumerate(cam_list):
    # Retrieve TL device nodemap
    if ID == cam_num:
        print ('Got cam')
        cam = cam

        cam.Init()

        # ... CV2 again ...

        for i in range(10):
            testDevice(i) # no printout
```

Comment: what is so special on Point Grey FLIR cameras?

Comment: also I am cofused - does this solution work for this kind of cameras (using PySpin wrapper?) Is this kind of camera useable with cv2 _at all_?

Comment: I don't know yet and trying to figure this out as we speak. I've migrated from PyCapture2 to PySpin but lost functions like cameraPowerON/OFF and a few more. There is a `isValid()` test I describe in another Q/A session that does more or less the trick (read: patchwork) but read/writeRegister functions are a lost case here. As far as I can see now they make use of the GENiCAM structured naming/framework and thus work with nodes and active camera instance (as seen in the code provided). Actually, I was kind of flabbergasted CV2 couldn't get its fingers behind the door in the camera.

Comment: Maybe you should create your own question then - this does not seem to be an answer to the original post. If you come to some answer, you probably could post a question/selfanswer to the likes of `how to detect amount of Pint Grey FLIR cameras` ...  they seem to have their _own_ kind of API:  https://www.flir.com/iis/machine-vision/

Comment: Sure but I know how to deal with the acquisition of images via PySpin and passing it to cv2 via a conversion. (cat and mice still on board ;-) This answer is specifically intended to help people avoid making that mistake and break their teeth on it. Hence the "NOT working" warning ;0

Comment: Imaging what happens if we collect all "NOT working" ways to do things as _answers_ to questions on SO ... your `cam = cam` does nothing by the way - it will be overwritten by the next value in your loop `for ID, cam in enumerate(cam_list):` and only ever have the _last_ camera object in it - not all. you mean well, but I guess this might get dv -you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import cv2

# detect all connected webcams
valid_cams = []
for i in range(8):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
    if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
        print('Warning: unable to open video source: ', i)
    else:
        valid_cams.append(i)

caps = []
for webcam in valid_cams:
    caps.append(cv2.VideoCapture(webcam))

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    for webcam in valid_cams:
        ret, frame = caps[webcam].read()
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('webcam'+str(webcam), frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == ord('q') or k == 27:
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
for cap in caps:
    cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```