# How do I know if my webcam is currently working? python, opencv

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

How do I know if my webcam is currently working? I tried to check " stream.read () " because it returns "None" when the camera is not active. But when the camera is active " stream.read () " returns an array and I get an error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". How do I fix this?
my code:

```
import cv2
import time
from tkinter import *

stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(10)
while True:

    r, f = stream.read ()
    a=f
    print(a)
    if a==None:
        print("No active")
    else:
        print("Active")

    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)
    # f = imutils.resize(f, width=400)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `f` is numpy's array and to check it is not `None` you have to check `if f is not None`` instead of `if f  == None:` . When `f` has array then `array == None` try to compare `None` with every element in array and it is ambiguous and it ask to use ` any()` or `all()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly check if a camera is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049886/how-to-correctly-check-if-a-camera-is-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` returns both an array and a boolean to indicate whether it was successful in reading a frame, the `r` in your code. Use that value instead:

```
if r == False:
        print("No frame read")
    else:
        print("Succes")
```

[docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1)

That checks if a frame was read. However, a frame might not be read even when the camera is active. The best way to check if the camera is active is to check :

```
open = stream.isOpened()

if open:
    print('Camera active')
```

[docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a9d2ca36789e7fcfe7a7be3b328038585)

Answer (score 1):

`f` is numpy's array and to check it is not `None` you have to check

```
 if f is None:
```

instead of

```
 if f == None:
```

When `f` has array then you compare `array == None` and it tries to compare `None` with every element in `array` and it is ambiguous - so it ask to use `any()` or `all()`