# Avoid `can't open camera by index`, when testing with cv2, all cam connected

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect all cameras pluged to a linuxbox.

The best I found is this:

```
import cv2

def test_open_cam():
    connected_cam = []
    for port in range(0, 10):
        try:
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture(port)
            if cam.isOpened():
                connected_cam.append(port)
            cam.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        except:
            cam.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print(f'=> list of found cameras: {connected_cam}')
    return(connected_cam)
```

When I run it I get it but with a lot of [ WARN:0]:

```
start
==> test port: 0
==> test port: 1
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
==> test port: 2
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video2): can't open camera by index
==> test port: 3
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video3): can't open camera by index
==> test port: 4
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video4): can't open camera by index
==> test port: 5
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video5): can't open camera by index
==> test port: 6
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video6): can't open camera by index
==> test port: 7
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video7): can't open camera by index
==> test port: 8
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video8): can't open camera by index
==> test port: 9
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video9): can't open camera by index
=> list of found cameras: [0]
```

How can I avoid all this `[ WARN:0] ...` and by the way avoid the ugly try: except ?

Note: using the proposition of Patrick Yeadon https://stackoverflow.com/a/61768256/3313834 from: [Listing available devices in python-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044539/listing-available-devices-in-python-opencv)

```
def test_open_cam():
    # checks the first 10 indexes.
    index = 0
    arr = []
    i = 10
    while i > 0:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
        if cap.read()[0]:
            arr.append(index)
            cap.release()
        index += 1
        i -= 1
    return arr
```

I still get the same `[ WARN:0]` on cv2.VideoCapture (after the first one)

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video2): can't open camera by index
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video3): can't open camera by index
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video4): can't open camera by index
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video5): can't open camera by index
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video6): can't open camera by index
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video7): can't open camera by index
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video8): can't open camera by index
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-99ib2vsi/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video9): can't open camera by index
```

Following  Christoph Rackwitz ideas I've try to replace `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(port)` with `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(port, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)`, no more WARN message ! but `cam.isOpened()` return False for all port ;(

```
>>> print(cv2.getBuildInformation()) 
...
  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.109.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.61.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.60.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.8.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing available devices in python-opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044539/listing-available-devices-in-python-opencv)

Comment: Check Patrick Yeadon‘a answer on above SO similar issue

Comment: Since you are using linux maybe this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051212/9758354

Comment: OpenCV tries different backends, V4L2 among them. if you don't want that, use `apiPreference=` to set a specific one. I would recommend CAP_FFMPEG.

Comment: Christoph, I've updated the question with your input

Comment: The CAP_FFMPEG not working is addressed in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65641483/3313834