# PYTHON - CV2 : Check if webcam is used by other app

Tags: python, macos, opencv, webcam

I'm trying to develop a code to **check if the WebCam is used by other app** (like Zoom, Skype etc...) using python and cv2.

For example, in macOS you can use this command in the TERMINAL `lsof | grep "VDC"` to see if the WebCam is running.

So I don't want to open it like in this code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if(cap.isOpened()):
    print("Camera conntected")
else:
    print("Alert ! Camera disconnected")`
```

**I want only to check if it is opened by other app or is closed and print 'Running' or 'Not running'.**

I prefer using python, but if there is other language fell free to report ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly check if a camera is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049886/how-to-correctly-check-if-a-camera-is-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment macOS does not allow users to see which app is using system resources as the camera, for privacy reasons.

You could, anyway, check out [this project](https://objective-see.com/products/oversight.html) that has achieved what you are looking for. Maybe, with a native implementation, you could be able to get the camera state or workaround it someway.

Answer (score 0):

even if it's not perfect, the "best" solution should be to use a try except and force it to 'bug' if the camera is already openned.
I try to access the Warnings from cv2 but it looks a bit hard.

Here is a code that works in your case:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if(cap.isOpened()):
    print("Camera conntected")
else:
    print("Alert ! Camera disconnected")

number_itteration = 0
while cap.isOpened():
    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if number_itteration == 0:
            print(len(frame))
    except Exception as e:
        print('camera already used')
        break
    number_itteration += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the quickest response!. This solution isn't working I run code and always run the Webcam And shows Camera conntected 720. If using CV2 is not possible Do you know any other library?

Comment: Or maybe I should use other languages?

Comment: really? I tried it on my computer and when I try to start 2 .py which use the webcam it goes to the except for the second one. It's not what you asked? Who use your webcam? another program (which is not a .py) ?

Comment: I run in macOS BigSur 11.2.3 and I’d like to detect if applications like chrome or zoom are using it. It is possible to do it?

Comment: This program should be Like the light of the webcam to know if it is on or off

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand what u mean. In the solution I wrote, it will detect if opencv already use the camera which avoid you to make it bug if you start the program multiple times. But as far as I know, opencv can get the camera image even if it's already used by zoom or something like this no?

Comment: I tried my code while using the camera with bluejeans and Zoom. With both app it says 'camera already used'. It's strange that you don't have this too.

Comment: Witch OS you use? I will try to emulate your environment

Comment: I tried on windows 10. On my MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 it doesn't work, I can even use it multiple times like you. I have no solution in that case..