# cv2 doesn't give an error in Python, so can't use it with except block

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, opencv

I'm using cv2 to start the camera in Python. I want it to be flexible, so it does not matter if the user is using a built-in cam or a USB one, it'd work. It would also show an error if the cam wasn't recognized.

This is how far I've written.

```
try:    
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            
except:
    try:
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
                
    except:
        print("")
        print("There was a problem accessing your camera, please try again")
        print("Exiting now...")
        time.sleep(10)
        exit()
```

The thing is, cv2 doesn't give a Python error if it does not detect a cam. It just gives the following warning:

```
[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-ddpkm6fn/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video2): can't open camera by index
```

So, the second except block is not executed, which would probably leave my users confused about the warning. How do I make it so that the except block is executed?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we check if the camera object is created or not, we can also check for camera.isopened() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try reading from the capture device just once to get one frame. As you know, there would be another value given when attempting to read a frame, and that value tells us if the read was successful:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
success, frame = camera.read()
if not success:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    success, frame = camera.read()
    if not success:
        print("")
        print("There was a problem accessing your camera, please try again")
        print("Exiting now...")
        time.sleep(10)
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cv2.VideoCapture( invalid device number ) does not throw exceptions. It constructs a  containing an invalid device - if you use it you get exceptions.

Test the constructed object for None and not isOpened() to weed out invalid ones.

```
import cv2 as cv 

def testDevice(source):
   cap = cv.VideoCapture(source) 
   if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
       print('Warning: unable to open video source: ', source)

testDevice(0) # no printout
testDevice(1) # prints message
```

I have taken the answer from - [How to correctly check if a camera is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049886/how-to-correctly-check-if-a-camera-is-available).

> **Note**: I initially checked the VideoCapture object using the help method provided i.e help(camera). help method in python helps to
> provide all the methods and attributes that are available for the
> object. It helps in debugging libraries and looking into methods and
> documentation quickly from console itself.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for importing cv2 as cv?

Comment: We can use cv2 as well. It is just easy to type cv. There is no functionality difference

Comment: @ShishirModi did the solution helped you in getting the work done?

Comment: It didn't work as I was expecting it to, it still gives a Warning